# How to align atom package to the right

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, package, atom-editor

I've a package in Atom that I created with JS, and I want to set its(Toggle's) position to the right. I researched a lot, but there is no information about javascript packages; all of them are about coffeescript. I found something like this:

```
# config:
#   browser:
#     type: "object"
#     properties:
#       position:
#         default: "right"
#         type: "string"
#         enum: ["top", "right", "bottom", "left"]
#       size:
#         type: "integer"
#         default: 450
```

I guess I can use `atom.config.set(keyPath, value, options)`, but I couldn't configure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the solution that i want -> in the your_package_name.js :**

**change**

```
this.modalPanel = atom.workspace.addModalPanel
```

**to**

```
this.modalPanel = atom.workspace.addRightPanel
```

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of that for an Atom package in Javascript would be:

```
config: {
  browser: {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      position: {
        default: 'right',
        type: 'string',
        enum: ['top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'],
      },
      size: {
        type: 'integer',
        default: 450,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would recommend placing this with the rest of your config options at or near the top of your code.